# Autodiscover additional POP account

Tags: windows, email, exchange, outlook

We have several domains beneath our main domain (`acme.com`). Employees have an Exchange account (`user@acme.com`) but occasionally need to send mails from the other domains too. To avoid having around 15 mailboxes for each user, we redirect every incoming mail into to the `user@acme.com` mailbox.
Employees have additional send-only accounts configured in Outlook (using a non-existent POP server `notused.lan` and the hosting provider's public SMTP server `smtp.foo.com`). That way, they can choose to send from one of the additional domains, sent emails will be stored in the Exchange sent folder and replies will be stored in the Exchange mailbox.

The downside is, once a user switches to another computer or a new user is created, we have to setup each account separately, requiring way too much support time.

**Is there a way to deploy POP accounts in addition to a users Exchange account via Autodiscover?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer no.
Autodiscover on Exchange cannot configure the POP3 accounts for you.

I don't like the POP3 dummy account method, as I find it causes more problems than it resolves and prefer the additional account method.

If you really have to send from a large number of domains, then something like ChooseFrom from ivasoft.biz would be a better option.